# How to optimize liquidsoap?

Tags: icecast, transcoding, internet-radio, liquidsoap

I want to relay ~40 radio with Icecast and transcode them to 3 bitrates(32,64,128)

Relay all radio and transcoding them to 32 bitrate working good, but on 64, 128 doesn't work

Liquidsoap logs:

```
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.04s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.02s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
2015/07/24 11:36:56 [:3] Buffer overrun: Dropping 0.03s.
```

Liquidsoap config:

```
set("buffering.kind","raw")
set("log.file", true)

def my_input(url) =
    mksafe(input.http(buffer=5., max=20., url));
end

def outputs(name, mount, input) =
    output.icecast(
    %mp3(bitrate=32, samplerate=22050, stereo=false),
    ******
    mean(input))

    output.icecast(
    %mp3(bitrate=64,samplerate=44100,stereo=true),
    ******
    input)

    output.icecast(
    %mp3(bitrate=128,samplerate=44100,stereo=true),
    ******
    input)

end

url = "http://localhost:8000/radio1"
input = my_input(url)
outputs("Radio1", "radio1", input)

#..............

url = "http://localhost:8000/radio40"
input = my_input(url)
outputs("Radio40", "radio40", input)
```

Icecast limits:

[image]

Server info:

```
6 cores(average load 40%)
6GB RAM
```

htop screen:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the load in this case is for the codec and there isn't a lot you'll be able to do to reduce it.  Split your transcoding across multiple servers.

For what it's worth, I can usually get 12 streams transcoded on the cheapest Digital Ocean box available.  If you're not already using cheap VPS hosting for this, I recommend it!  Just be sure to monitor CPU with something like New Relic and move to a new host should they cut into the cycles you're allocated.  Your codec needs a constant availability of CPU to keep buffers full.

Also, I don't know what your source stream is but I highly recommend starting with a lossless source.  Lossy codecs reduce quality and using more than one of them in a chain reduces it further.

Comment: How i can to do in on 1 server? I want to order dedicated server but donn't know which one to order in my case (. And how to configure liquidsoap to begin transcoding only if there is one or more listeners?

Comment: @IceJOKER Don't use one server, use multiple.  Better to use more smaller servers to split the load than one big one.  It's usually cheaper that way, and then you can take down part of your rig for updates without shutting it all down.

Comment: in this case, how i can to join my domain ? I have domain: example.com and i want to stream radio via domain(NOT IP): example.com:8000/mount_1_32 ... example.com:8000/mount_40_128

I know how to do it with one server, but not several servers.

Comment: @IceJOKER You can host your server wherever you want, and still have separate Liquidsoap instances.  Leave Icecast on `example.com` and have other servers for running Liquidsoap.

Comment: can U show how can i to do it? for example: on first server are installed IceCast2 + liquidsoap which one transcode and stream 10 radio, how to configure second & third server to for other 20 radio? (I need just example for 1 radio)

Comment: @IceJOKER Instead of using `localhost:8000`, use `example.com:8000` for your Liquidsoap outputs.  That's all there is to it.  It doesn't matter where you put the Liquidsoap instances.  They connect to Icecast over HTTP.  As for how to split your Liquidsoap script up, it's hard to say without seeing your whole script.  What I do though is have a separate script for each channel.  Within that script are all the different bitrates.  So for RadioReddit, we have 8 genre channels with 4 streams each.  There is a common included file and the whole thing is in version control.

Comment: @IceJOKER We deploy the whole repo to each streaming box, but then symlink 3 or 4 of the Liquidsoap config files in /etc/liquidsoap.  When the init.d script runs, it just loads those symlinked files.

Answer (score 1):

In our case we setup input.http(max=20.,URL) and problem solved!